# Which child class object exists at a certain index

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am working on an assignment of making a paint brush application using the GP142 graphics library on C++

the hierarchy is as follows
Abstract class shape
Circle, polygon and openshape class inherits from shape, polygon and  openshape are abstract too
rectangle, triangle, general polygon and quadrilateral inherit from polygon
line and curve inherit from openshape
now in my main program, i have a pointer

```
shape ** allshapes = new shape * [1];
```

as more shapes are added, size is increased and when they are removed, size is reduced.
now i want to add a save and load function. I can save all of the data to a file but how exactly am i supposed to know that which data belongs to which shape. for example, rectangle, and line both require only two points.
Similarly, in general, if i want to know which shape is on which index, how would i know?

Comment: `std::vector` is better than raw pointers.

Comment: Your data serialization should include all info needed to reconstruct object (including its real type).

Comment: @Jarod42 Anything is better than using raw pointers.

Comment: what's with the pointer phobia with C++ programmers?

Comment: Not so much a phobia as having better ways to handle pointers. Look up the [smart pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer#C.2B.2B_smart_pointers) support in the standard library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't expected to know. Add to the base class a pure virtual function, say

```
virtual std::ostream & serialize(std::ostream & out) = 0;
```

Which must be implemented by each subclass and performs the serialization specific to the subclass. Likewise, you can add a

```
std::string & whatAmI() = 0;
```

function to tell you what the Shape is, but using this information in the code is problematic. For example, what do you do if another coder adds class MobiusParallelogram which returns an unrecognized string? Better to embrace encapsulation and have all of the subclass specific stuff hidden and handled inside the object.

Reiterating the point on using std:vector over performing your own array management. It will save you a lot of time and trouble.

If you cannot use std:: vector in the constraints of the assignment and have to do it the hard way, don't allocate one at a time because your program will be spending a lot of time resizing and copying data from old array to new array, plus the behind the scenes activities resulting from fragmenting your memory with large number of allocations and deallocations. Consider doubling the size every time the array needs to be resized and don't shrink the array unless you have to. Keeping the array the exact right size gains you nothing, as a pointer to an array doesn't know how big the contained array is.